# React Typescript: Get files from file input

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The error I get is `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` Why cant I access the files array from the file input?

Is this a case where useRef is ok to use?

```
import React from 'react';
const Photo: React.FC = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    photo: '',
  });

  const {
    photo,
  } = state;

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    event.persist();
    setState((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
    }));
    console.log(state.photo) // returns nothing
    console.log(event.files[0]);
//                      ^
//                      Property 'files' does not exist on type 
  };

  return (
    <div className='photo'>
      <label>
        Click Me
        <input
          type='file'
          id='photo'
          name='photo'
          accept='image/png, image/jpeg'
          onChange={onChange}
          value={photo}
        ></input>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`files` is property of an input ([`HTMLInputElement`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L7298)) and not of the event.

So it should be `event.currentTarget.files`

Answer (score 7):

I use this way to add files

```
const onChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
  const files = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

  if (files) {
    setFormData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      images: files,
    }));
  }
};
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting it.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    console.log(state.photo) // returns nothing
```

This returns nothing because when you set state its value is available on the next render cycle. So if you select another file with your file input, then, `console.log(state.photo)` will log the previous file name.

If you want to log the current selected file, use:

```js
    console.log(event.target.value)
```

Take a look at my example: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cdn-1fnuv

And

```js
    console.log(event.files[0]);
```

will throw error. Don't use it.

Comment: the result is `C:\fakepath\Screenshot 2019-12-06 at 12.11.29 PM.png` im expecting an object like `File {name: "Screenshot 2019-12-08 at 12.12.08 AM.png", lastModified: 1575735133974, lastModifiedDate: Sun Dec 08 2019 00:12:13 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 95373, …}`

Comment: Use 
`console.log('Current file: ' + JSON.stringify({
      name: event.target.files[0].name,
      lastModified: event.target.files[0].lastModified,
      size: event.target.files[0].size
    }))`

Answer (score 1):

```
const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
const handleChangeFile = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const files = e.currentTarget.files
    if (files)
        setFile(files[0])
}
<input
  type={'file'}
  multiple={false}
  accept="application/pdf"
  onChange={handleChangeFile}
   />
```