# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting this TypeError

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')
```

and cannot find a solution. my app is using react and I'm getting this error while handling a setState hook.

```
 const handleCapImage = (event) => {
    setPostImage(event.target.files[0]);
  };
```

React element where I'm calling it

```
<input
    type="file"
    id="file"
    ref={inputFile}
    style={{ display: "none" }}
    onChange={handleCapImage}
 />
```

Comment: How, and where, are you calling `handleCapImage`? There is no code in your question for us to debug why `event.target` is undefined.

Comment: @Terry I'm calling it inside of an <input onChange={handleCapImage}>

Comment: Does this work for you onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target.files)} I just tried it in sandbox, it works there

Comment: Also that input you have sent in the comment above... Does it have a type="file"? If that's the entire input you have in your code, it cannot work because you are trying to read file on text input.

Comment: @MalwareMoon console.log(event.target.files) works perfectly in handleCapImage function. it returns "FileList {0: File, length: 1}"

Comment: @ MalwareMoon however my function is working perfectly but it's catching this error.

Comment: this is the <input type="file" id="file" ref={inputFile} style={{ display: "none" }} onChange={handleCapImage}
          /> element

Comment: You are not on typescript are you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249154/discussion-between-hishan-98-and-malwaremoon).

Answer (score 0):

files is property of an input (HTMLInputElement) and not of the event.

So it should be `event.currentTarget.files`

Also make sure your input is actually of type="file"

**Edit** (Now that there is more info)

I cannot seem to find anything wrong with it. Make sure you are not doing something on that ref that triggers on change before the file is there. It's cheap, but as of now I would suggest just adding

```js
if(event.target && event.target.files) {
  setPostImage(event.target.files[0]);
} else {
  setPostImage(undefined);
}
```

Comment: Source here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233036/react-typescript-get-files-from-file-input

Comment: this is probably the right solution, but the wrong explanation. Because event.target returns an element (just as event.currentTarget does - they just might be different ones depending on the circumstances).

Comment: @MalwareMoon thanks for the solution but the error is still occurring.

Comment: And did you make sure that onchange is not evoked before you input file is set or that the handle function is invoked by something else? I did spend with it quite a bit and could not reproduce the behavior you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` is refering to the element, from which the event originates. `event.currentTarget` refers to the element that the eventListener is on. I guess your event is bubbeling to the element with the eventlistener, so you are accesing the wrong element (because I guess you want the element the eventListener is on)

Comment: still says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')" after I change it to "currentTarget".

Answer (score 0):

`inputFile.current.files[0]` should work if the handler function is inside your component.

Comment: inputFile.current.files[0] works well but it's catching that TypeError

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).